# Ubuntu 17.10 Boots 90 degrees

Tags: 17.10

Trying to install 17.10 on Asus laptop.  16.04 worked fine but 17.10 boots 90 degrees off (screen is rotated as if a tablet was rotated).  Laptop is a trasformer type so if I rotate is rotates the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The installation disk will show the screen 90 degrees off.  When installed, the screen will right itself very nicely.  To correct the screen from the the DVD boot, open a terminal and type..."gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true"

Answer (score 0):

There is the button available - I simply turned my laptop 90 degrees until the screen orientation was how I wanted it. Then, in the upper right corner, click the drop-down arrow...

Right next to the Power Button, is an Orientation-Lock button. You will notice once you return your laptop to the correct rotation that the desktop orientation has been locked to the correct orientation.