# 17.10 - ASUS T103 with ASUS Pen rotated input by 90 degrees

Tags: asus, input-devices, display-rotation, 18.04

I install and Ubuntu 17.10 and later 18.04 on a ASUS Transformer mini T103. From the beginning the boot screen is rotated by 90 degrees ccw off like it is described [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008893/ubuntu-17-10-boots-90-degrees).

The login screen has than the correct orientation, but the behaviour of the ASUS Pen is the same as it is still rotated. If I tip on the upper left corner using the pen, the pointer shows up in the upper right. If I move than down, the pointer moves left. If I touch on the screen with the finger all goes right.

It seem as if there a transformation issue. How shall I continue?

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

## rotate touch screen

`xinput set-prop 14 --type=float 154 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1`

## rotate pen input

`xinput set-prop 21 --type=float 154 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1`

I'm sorry but I can't remember what the strings for props 14 and 21 are.

Comment: use `xinput list` to find input devices and there ID's.